# filter user records based on their names

Tags: python, django

I simply have a django medical website where users have their medical records and can view when logged in.
I have achieved  the filtering based on user that is logged in, what i want is another user(doctor) to see this records based on user(patient he selects). currently the doctor can see if the record is one(using get_object_or_404, but i want loop over many records.

The models.py

```
class Medrecs(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="meds")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey('Doctors.Doctor', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    meds = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Views.py

```
def detail(request, pat_id):
    patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=pat_id)
    medrecs = Medrecs.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'MyDoc/detail_pat.html', {'patient': patient}, {'medrecs': medrecs})
```

In the view above i can see the patient records which are single records, but the medrecs(Medical records am unable to filter them based on the user(patient), it just gives me the page with the code(the template page unexecuted ). Medrecs.objects.filter(user=request.user) same case, .get will bring the number of rows and an error multipleobjects returned.

As a side note i was able to filter this records in the user's(profile page) with the view:

```
def my_profile(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    meds = Medrecs.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'MyDoc/my_profile.html', {'meds': meds})
else:
    return redirect('MyDoc:login_patient')
```

Asking for help please.And thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the problem may be that you are using the wrong field to filter. Why do you have the user as a foreign key?. If you are saving Medrecs to a doctor and a patient maybe you should filter this way.

```
#you are filtering the medrecs by the user field
medrecs = Medrecs.objects.all().filter(user=request.user) 


#Instead try this (if the doctor is logged in)
doctor = """your_get_doctor_method"""
medrecs = Medrecs.objects.all().filter(doctor=doctor,patient__id=pat_id)
```